# Как узнать расширение файла FileStream?

Tags: c#, filestream

Имеется функция, которой на вход поступает объект класса FileStream. Необходимо узнать его расширение (png,txt,bmp или другое).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так выглядит функция:

```
 public void Info(FileStream stream)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("тут должно быть расширение");
        }
```

Comment: Path.GetExtension(stream.Name)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Получение информации из файла stream C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1025067/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-stream-c)

Comment: А как связан скрин ошибки и код? На картинке ошибка для базового класса Stream, а в коде FileStream, для которого этой ошибки быть просто не может, т.к. свойство Name у FileStream есть, а вот у базового Stream естественно его нет.